# How to create an enum intended hardcoded strings for global calls

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I want to create an enum for storing hardcoded strings in SwiftUI. What is the best way to implement this?

I have already tried creating a `@BindableObject`, which made things quite a bit complicated. I have also tried creating the enum as an extension, separate model in a separate file, or within and/or outside the struct, but no luck whatsoever.

Also following this, I need to be able to use these hardcoded points to call specific information from the JSON file called in `ItemRow`. Best way to do this is to create a separate file I guess, but I'm stuck at the first level.

Below is the enumeration I'm trying to create

```
enum Sections: String {
    case one = "Header 1"
    case two = "Header 2"
    case three = "Header 3"
    case four = "Header 4"
}
```

And this is my Section:

```
Section(header: Sections.one) {
    Section(header: Sections.two.font(.headline)) {
        ForEach(userData.items) { item in
            NavigationLink(destination:
                ItemDetailView(userData: UserData(), item: item)) {
                    ItemRow(item: item)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> Referencing initializer 'init(header:content:)' on 'Section' requires that 'ItemListView.Sections' conform to 'View'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

1. To get the string from your enum, you need to use `rawValue`. That is, `Sections.one.rawValue`, `Sections.two.rawValue`, etc.
2. The Section header parameter requires a View, not a String. So you should change:

```swift
Section(header: Sections.one)
```

with

```swift
Section(header: Text(Sections.one.rawValue))
```

And finally,

3. The font modifier needs to be applied to a Text view, not a string, so you need to also change:

```swift
Section(header: Sections.two.font(.headline))
```

to

```swift
Section(header: Text(Sections.two.rawValue).font(.headline))
```